# Pre-Windows Dialog on Dell All-in-one Machine

Tags: boot, desktop-computer, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 320 which is displaying this message on bootup after the BIOS screens but before the Windows splash screen. Does anyone know what this might be or can anyone translate this? Note the "20" on the last line is a counter.

[image: Dell Boot Message]

Comment: Wow, and you purchased this in an English speaking country?

Comment: Yes. Windows is still in English when it boots as well. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone at a local Chinese restaurant helpfully helped us get this translated. I don't have an exact translation, but it is a request to insert the system recovery disk. The first button is to proceed with system recovery. The second button is to boot Windows normally. I suspect the user may have run this tool by accident and did not tell me about it. How it got in Chinese, though, we have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

I had that exact same error, but I managed to type the Chinese into Google and find a solution. Our problem was a BIOS setting called "HDD Protection Feature" under the advanced tab. Somehow this had been enabled and we didn't have the necessary hardware to make use of it, so this error popped up. Once we disabled it, the message disappeared.

I realize this question was asked quite a while ago, but there doesn't seem to be an answer in English anywhere. For reference, the title of the box is 增霸卡 v2.20(For Dell), and the first few words are 系统安装, or "System Installation".